# Is it possible to "apt install" in SageMaker Studio Lab?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have started using SageMaker Studio Lab.

When I run "apt install xvfb" in SageMaker Studio Lab Notebook, I get the following error.

```
!apt install xvfb

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Then I tried with sudo, but the sudo command was not installed.

```
!sudo apt install xvfb

/usr/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date Studio Lab doesn't support package installs that require root access. It does support packages installable via pip and conda. You can do that either in your notebook with the %, rather than the !, or you can do that via opening a terminal.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lab-use-manage.html

If you'd like to open an issue you're welcome to do that on our repository right here:

- https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/blob/main/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug-report-for-sagemaker-studio-lab.md

Thanks for trying out Studio Lab!

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the information. I will read the documentation carefully and learn.

Comment: Here is the correct link to open an issue (bug report, feature request) for SageMaker Studio Lab: https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues

Comment: That is rather unfortunate

Answer (score 1):

Use yum instead of apt

```
!sudo yum install -y xvfb
```