Install Build-Essential and libgmp3-dev
I am trying to find out how to install build-essential libgmp3-dev in the notebook under Ubuntu terminal.
It won't take it with the traditional sudo apt install.
Any help would be truly appreciated.
I am just trying to install those packages.

https://installati.one/install-libgmp3-dev-ubuntu-22-04/

I just tried and was able to install them from the Terminal session.
$ sudo apt install build-essential libgmp3-dev

$ sudo apt list --installed | grep -E 'libgmp3|build-essential'
build-essential/jammy,now 12.9ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
libgmp3-dev/jammy,now 2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

Are you seeing different behavior?

Hey buddy. Thanks for your comment. From Terminal, I am not able to use sudo, are you using Sagemaker Studio Lab's platform?

Hi Sebastian, I am using SageMaker Studio's JupyterLab, not SageMaker Studio Lab.
I found this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70202848/is-it-possible-to-apt-install-in-sagemaker-studio-lab/70204408. According to the answer, Studio Lab environment allows you to get root and sudo. Consider using regular SageMaker Studio (paid version).

"SageMaker Studio Lab" (free) environment doesn't allow you to get root privilege. Please use regular SageMaker Studio (paid) environment. You can use sudo there.
